# Implementing custom authorization filter to ASP.Net Web API

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-authorization

First time I am implementing authorization in ASP.Net Web API. I have a requirement to implement custom authorization for my web API project. The requirement is to authorize the users against an existing table. I came across [this](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2988903/application-architecture/how-to-secure-web-api-using-authorization-filters.html) link. I want to know how the unauthorized request is handled? How do we make sure that "HandleUnauthorizedRequest" sends the "unauthorized" message and do not let the application execute the API method. Specifically what to write in:

```
HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
//Code to handle unauthorized request. Give the user error message instead of serving the request.
}
```

Is there any better way to implement SQL table based authorization for ASP.Net Web API?

Comment: Before answering Authorization part, how do you manage Authentication? It is all depend of how you implement authentication part.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Using an Authorization Filter is one option. If the authorization fails you can return an instance of [UnauthorizedException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx) class or even a custom [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx).

Another option is to use an AuthorizeAttribute or specifically a [Custom AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707357(v=vs.91).aspx).

That being said - with the Authorization Filter option you can do something like the following:

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
           // your custom authorization logic
           if not authorized // pseudo code
              filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                return;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            return;
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(Unauthorized);
    }
```

You may want to consider using a framework such as [ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity) vs. your custom solution.